# Codeigniter - share project files for duplicating website to mobile website

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory-structure

I need to replicate the website on another domain.
the both domains will share same db and same logic behind.

Now assuming this is my application scheme.

```
application
js
css
system
.htaccess
index.php
```

Which is the best practice do replicate the site for the other domain ?

What i need to know before to start ?

**NB:** basically i just have to duplicate the html,css  and js , for mobile site domain so i'll have www.site.com and www.mobile.site.com

Comment: Are both sites going to be hosted on the same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your directory structure could look like:

```
-/home/yourdomain
    -public_html
        -index.php
        -.htaccess
        -mobile
            -index.php
            -.htaccess
        -assets
            -js
            -css
            -img
            -etc
    -your_application
        -system
        -application
```

To share the same CodeIgniter installation and application, you could place the `system` and `application` folder above the web root - which is a good idea anyway (in this example it is in the `your_application` directory).

Assuming that your domain is pointing to: `public_html` and the mobile domain is pointing to:  `public_html/mobile`, then you would add CodeIgniter's default `index.php` to both locations. Update both of these files to point to the system folder and application folder:

```
$system_folder = /home/yourdomain/your_application/system;
$application_folder= /home/yourdomain/your_application/application;
```

The assets are publicially accessible, so just ensure that the HTML you generate points to the correct location, for example: `http://yourdomain.com/assets/css/main.css`